# Android slow AES decryption

Tags: java, android, openssl, android-ndk, aes

Ref: [Android encryption/decryption issue (AES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813151/android-encryption-decryption-issue-aes)

I am building an android app which requires aes decryption of a really large package (~50Mb) and it is really slow when implemented in android's inbuilt aes decryption mechanism (around 5 minutes).

Based on the above posts in SO, I attempted to use ndk and tried to download native libraries (openssl) to use for this app. However, openssl for android has a really large number of files and I do not know which ones to use to create the .so file.

I am quite inexperienced with the use of ndk and native code in android apps and would find any suggestions/sample code on how to use openssl library for aes decryption really useful.

Thanks in advance,
Naveen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [SpongyCastle](https://github.com/rtyley/spongycastle#readme) its a repackaged BouncyCastle that wont conflict with the one released with Android. The one on Android systems is old (if you even have a release of Android that includes it).

This should be all you need.

Comment: Wasn't BouncyCastle Android's provider?

Comment: Yes on most releases it is. But last I checked its a really old version. Search SO for this issue. And due to the Classloader issues in Jre6 you can't replace bouncycastle with a newer one, thus the rename for Android.

Comment: Hi Andrew. Just saw your reply. Thanks. I shall try to implement it and get back to you.

Comment: Hi. We tried SpongyCastle but faced difficulties in getting it to work. Now this may simply be because we are inexperienced developers and not because the library cannot do our job. However, we did manage to use this library from Chillkat (have to pay after 30 day trial) which provides a java wrapper around the ndk and got it to work. Decryption time went down from 5 minutes to just 25 seconds.

Comment: @Naveen LP Good find. Glad you found something to work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue as Naveen.

I do have some doubts regarding spongy castle. Correct me if i'm wrong.
This post i've found: http://www.coderanch.com/t/134504/Security/Bouncy-Castle-vs-Sun-JCE
Seems like performance might be negligible. Though it did not specifically mentioned about spongycastle.bouncycastle but i'm assuming it is, as sun jce's crypto library uses a stripped down version of bouncy castle.

Comment: Something to keep in mind. No Sun software exists on any Android device. This is a bold statement I'm making and hopefully someone can prove me wrong. Google has their own JVM and potentially class libraries. The libraries most likely are from OpenJDK which I suppose Sun employees worked on. But don't confuse the code running on Android with the code running on your Windows machine when you download the Oracle JDK.

Comment: thanks andrew. i've researched for quite a while and there isn't any helpful article on how to do decryption of large files in an android device.